# Compiling single large header file (VS: C1063)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, header-files

I am attempting to compile a book into my executable.

This book MUST be compiled into my executable.  I cannot have a file I read from or some other database management system.

Currently, I have the text of my book in a single header file that has a function returning a string of the text.

The problem is this header file is 47,000+ lines long and 4MB+ large.

I attempt to test this file in my main.cpp file like so:

```
#include "MyBook.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     auto myBookStr = MyBook_ToString();
     loadMyBook(myBookStr);
}
```

I get the following error when compiling with VS2012 64bit Release:

fatal error C1063: compiler limit : compiler stack overflow

What is the best way to resolve this issue?  Off the top of my head, the only thing I can think to do is split the header into multiple files with a function that returns a string in each of them.  Is there a more elegant solution for compiling large header files?

Comment: The proper way to include large amounts of static data in a Windows executable is via a resource script.

Comment: Either that, or a big global variable; check out `xxd` with the `-i` option.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Several compilers have relatively small limits on the maximum size of globals IIRC, an embedded resource is the way to go.

Comment: consider https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html

Comment: Some compilers don't support resources, so data statements are one method.  In our embedded system, we have to convert font bitmaps into data statements, and link them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is 4 years overdue. The solution I ended up going with was to increase the width of my file and shorten its length.

Example:
MyBook was originally about 50k lines of text that I was trying to compile in a single cpp file. I was able to reduce this length down to just 250 lines of code my increasing the string width. MSVC and GCC/Clang have a character limit for a single line. By writing text up to 16000 character width per line, I was able to reduce the file length. Once I did that, the file compiled very quickly and no compiler stack overflow was hit.

Answer (score 4):

I really hate when people put data into a header file.

Move all the data into a source file, if you must compile the data into your executable.

For example:
**book.cpp:**

```
const char Book1_text[] = 
"Four score and seventy years ago"
" our forefathers came to this island"
" to consume our every byte of data"
//...
" and thus ends my book."
```

**book.hpp:**

```
#ifndef BOOK_HPP
#define BOOK_HPP
extern const char Book1_text[];
#endif // BOOK_HPP
```

The source file allows you to compile your data once and then after, only if the contents change.

When you place the data into a header, every file that includes the header gets the data and the header is compiled.  If I make a change to one of those source files, the book data gets compile again because it is in a header file.

Do you really **need** to have the data in your executable?

Can it be in text file outside your program?

Can it be in a database?

**Edit 1:**
You could break up the book into chapters and have each chapter as a separate data statement, or even as a separate data statement in a separate file.

Breaking up into chapters allows you to create an array of pointers to chapters.  This would help indexing and advancing a lot easier.  If you need to advance to chapter 9, just go to slot 9 in the index and pull out the pointer. :-)

### Generation of Data Files

In many shops, rather than hand-type all the data statements, they create a small application that takes a source (like a text file) and converts it into C data statements.  This allows easier updating of the original text file (once) and then simple generation into data statements.  Otherwise the propagations of text edits becomes unwieldly.